# p-calendar set predefined multiple date range?

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to set two range for p-calendar. For example to enable only current date and all dates in next month. Any suggestion?

I tried this:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" selectionMode="range" readonlyInput="true" ></p-calendar>

ngOnInit () {
        let today = new Date();
        let firstDate = new Date();
        firstDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
        this.rangeDates = [ firstDate, today];
    }
```

But this will give me only one range in this example it is last seven days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `numberOfMonths` property.

In your template,

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" selectionMode="range" [numberOfMonths]='2'  readonlyInput="true" ></p-calendar>
```